# Scrapy install fail - error of exit status 1

Tags: python, scrapy

```
    copying src\twisted\test\key.pem.no_trailing_newline -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\test
copying src\twisted\test\server.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\test
copying src\twisted\test\test_defer.py.3only -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\test
copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\notes.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\iocpreactor
copying src\twisted\internet\test\_awaittests.py.3only -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\test
copying src\twisted\internet\test\_yieldfromtests.py.3only -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\test
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\chain.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\not-a-certificate -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing1.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2-duplicate.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\mail\test\rfc822.message -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\mail\test
copying src\twisted\python\test\_deprecatetests.py.3only -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\python\test
copying src\twisted\trial\test\_assertiontests.py.3only -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\trial\test
copying src\twisted\words\im\instancemessenger.glade -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\words\im
copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\words\xish
running build_ext
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I tried to install scrapy via the command prompt, typing in `pip install scrapy`. it downloaded something, started installing but soon exited in failure. below are the last lines of a massive error log;

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\thega\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o99u8knn\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\thega\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o99u8knn\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\thega\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b2nn016h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: wanted to add that the error log it says to go and look at doesn't exist :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0?

The last line in the error log says:

```sh
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/"
```

The link works fine for me.

Comment: thank you Callum, my tired eyes missed that, i now have it installed and scrapy is up and running for me, thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear - happy scraping!